# IIS site cannot create (unwanted) App_Data Directory

Tags: iis, msdeploy, csproj

So Recently we've been updating our C# codebase to Net48, with the Microsoft.Net.Sdk project type (easier package management, more microsoft managed options) However it seems that when running site code, the code now tries to produce an "App_Data" directory in our IIS webroot.

Thing is, We don't allow our apppools the right to create any new files in the IISwebroot, instead allowing config files to determine in code where our supplemental directories should be created.

How can we force the code to stop trying to create this directory again? And any more supplemental documentation of updating projects would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems that your application is creating App_Data in your IIS webroot. IIS request 
 filter block the access to this folder so it shouldn't take risk. If you want to restrict the permission to create APP_Data, then you could use process monitor to trace this behavior and it will tell you who and what permission are used to create this folder.

Comment: My team debugged the code to figure out what was creating the request in the first place. I will look into using your method as well, but I've post the answer below in "Answers"

Answer (score 0):

We figured out our problem: The middleware was trying to create some database connection data and store it inside the App_data directory in the IIS webroot.

When adding this entry to the web.config under "AppSettings", it disables this feature:

```
<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
```

once SimpleMembership is disabled, the code doesn't try to create the directory for this reason